# Extract data from two files

Tags: text-processing, ksh, aix

I have two files as given below

Output1.csv

```
201319107648361,12:27:04,12:27:14,0:0:10 secs
201319109089878,12:27:04,12:27:15,0:0:11 secs
201319108968961,12:27:15,12:27:54,0:0:9 secs
201319108686853,12:27:34,12:27:43,0:0:9 secs
.
.
.
n
```

Output2.csv

```
201319107648361,200
201319109089878,129
201319108968961,719
201319108686853,412
.
.
.
n
```

I need to merge these two files in to a single file with one condition i.e if the first field of both the file are same.

For Instance,

If the first value or field of Output1.csv - **201319107648361** is equal to the first field of Output2.csv then need to print the remaining field of the files in to another file.

Desired output file should contain:

```
201319107648361,12:27:04,12:27:14,0:0:10 secs,200
201319109089878,12:27:04,12:27:15,0:0:11 secs,129
201319108968961,12:27:15,12:27:54,0:0:9 secs,719
201319108686853,12:27:34,12:27:43,0:0:9 secs,412
.
.
.
n
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is `join`

```
join -t\, <(sort Output1.csv) <(sort Output2.csv)
-or-
join -t "," <(sort Output1.csv) <(sort Output2.csv)
```

or `awk`

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{ print $0 "," a[$1]}' Output2.csv Output1.csv
```

Comment: @Ram - ask the author, I just edited the A.

Comment: $slm:sorry for the previous comment.

Comment: @dchirikov: It worked perfectly thanks for the help...:)

Comment: @Ram - np, please mark this as the accepted answer so that others know the issue's been resolved.